# Getting 404 when starting Tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

I configured Tomcat server version 9.0 to run in Eclipse. When I start it from Eclipse, it shows as started on port 8080. When I try accessing the location http://localhost:8080 from the browser or from inside Eclipse I get Http error 404. If I start Tomcat server from command line it starts also without any issues but I don't get the 404 error and page displays correctly. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're seeing two different sets of webapps. The default Tomcat installation includes a ROOT webapp that Eclipse does not deploy; it's what's handling the server-wide root page.